Extending Frobenius theorem on division algebras for division algebras with involution
Let $D$ be a real division algebra, either $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, or the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$. Define the involution $*$ as the trivial map on $\mathbb{R}$, complex conjugation on $\mathbb{C}$, and the standard involution $*:a
+bi+cj+dk\mapsto a-bi-cj-dk$ on $\mathbb{H}$.
I want to prove if $W$ be an orthogonal irreducible representation, then $\left(\text{End}_G(W),*\right) \cong \left(D,*\right)$, where $*$ acts as adjoint in $\text{End}_G(W)$. We know $\text{End}_G(W)$ is a division algebra by Schur's lemma, and it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, or $\mathbb{H}$ by Frobenius theorem on finite-dimensional real associative division algebras. How can I prove the rest?
I have asked a similar question in math.StackExchange without any answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4968095/real-division-algebras-with-involution
